# method referencing for custom class method

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following code:

```
    Map<String, ReportConfig> reportConfigMap = reportFactory.getReportConfigMap();

    List<String> resultList = reportConfigMap.values()
            .parallelStream()
            .filter(Utility::shouldReportVisibleToUser)
            .map(ReportConfig::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**ReportConfig Class Code**

```
public class ReportConfig implements Comparable<ReportConfig> {
  private String name;
  public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

for the portion of code `.map(ReportConfig::getName)`, I am passing the method reference of getName method using `ReportConfig::getName` which looks like as if getName is static method of ReportConfig class but actually it is the non-static method of that class.

If I try to do the same thing in my custom function, then java gives error which says: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method`. For example following code will not work:

```
    public class Test{
      public static void main (String[] agrs){
         Test test = new Test();
         test.executeService(Test::test);
      }
      public static ReportConfig executeService(Function<? extends ReportConfig,? extends ReportConfig> mapper){
        return mapper.apply(null);
      }

      public ReportConfig test(ReportConfig r){
        return r;
      }

    }
```

My question is how it if working for `map` method of stream and not working for my custom method? Is there anything I am doing wrong or I completely misunderstood something?

Comment: You want test::test, not Test::test.

Comment: Yes..I know that...But that's not the question.

Comment: `Test::test` takes two inputs: `this`, of type Test, `r`, of type ReportConfig, and returns a ReportConfig. So you could pass such a method reference as a BiFunction<Test, ReportConfig, ReportConfig>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReportConfig::getName` is roughly equivalent to:

```
public static String getName(ReportConfig arbitraryObject) {
    ...
}
```

The compiler searches the `ReportConfig` class for a method that matches the above signature. Since instance methods implicitly take `this` as the first parameter, the compiler finds the instance method `getName()` to be applicable. Furthermore, this signature matches the type arguments of a `Function<ReportConfig, String>`, so everything works fine.

On the other hand, going with the same inference as above, `Test::test` would be equivalent to:

```
public static ReportConfig test(Test arbitraryObject, ReportConfig r) {
    return r;
}
```

In this case, the compiler finds the method `public ReportConfig test(ReportConfig r)` which matches the above signature, but
which **cannot be converted to a `Function<? extends ReportConfig,? extends ReportConfig>`** (it would be converted to a `BiFunction<Test, ReportConfig, ReportConfig>` instead). Therefore the compiler resorts to finding a static `test` method, which does not exist.

To make it compile, either make the `test` method static, or use `test::test` instead of `Test::test`.

Comment: I think you mean the first imaginary method to be static, and the second one to be static and take a Test instance (`this`) as its first argument.

Comment: Yes indeed makes sense to be `static`, since the instance would be captured in the imaginary equivalent.

Comment: And again, the first argument to the second method would be of type Test, not ReportConfig.

Comment: Yes that's a typo. Thanks @JBNizet!

Comment: I did not get the concept of "hidden arbitrary instance", can you point to the documentation from where you read it?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari a function is something taking inputs as parameters, and returning something. A static method is just that: it takes parameters, and returns something. An instance method is not exactly that: it actually always has an implicit additional parameter: `this`, i.e. the object on which the method is called.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari Exactly what JB Nizet said, and also have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html from the Oracle tutorials where they explain the different kinds of method references with examples.

Comment: SO in order to make that work, what change I have to do?

Comment: @Prerak Tiwari: you already created a `Test` instance, but you don’t use it. You can change the code to `Test test = new Test(); test.executeService(test::test);` (note that `Test` changed to `test`). Or just `test.executeService(new Test()::test);` (this still creates only *one* instance of `Test`.

Comment: I just created to demonstrate the error but actually wanted to call it with Test::test

Comment: never mind...I got the concept now. Thank you for the explanation.